# switch signInAudience from AzureADMyOrg to AzureADMultipleOrgs azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito

[image]

i want to switch **signInAudience** in the manifest from "**AzureADMyOrg**" to "**AzureADMultipleOrgs**" in the manifest and i find in the documentation that **identifierURIs** MUST to be globally unique, can some one explaine this point please.

ps: I'm using the aws cognito urn as identifierURIs  ( urn:amazon:cognito:sp:< ID > )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"MUST be globally unique" means that it must be different from any other identifierURIs in any other tenants.

Because "AzureADMultipleOrgs" means your app is for multi-tenant, if your identifierURI is the same as others', your customers will not be able to access your app through this identifierURI because it points to multiple apps. This will cause confusion.

You can't set urn:amazon:cognito:sp:< ID > as identifierURIs because **urn** is no longer supported for identifierURIs currently. It has nothing to do with "MUST be globally unique".